# Question about redux component render method

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have three components which all of them connect to redux store and display the same state, let's called it `x`

And the three connected component have a parent-child relationship like:

```
- connect()(ComponentA)
  - connect()(ComponentB)
  - connect()(ComponentC)
```

ComponentB and ComponentC both are children of ComponentA

When I change the value of `x` in connected ComponentC, the `x` display also changed in ComponentA and ComponentB, but how many times the render method in ComponentB invoked?

In theory it should invoke twice (One by Parent Componet A, and one by itself), actully it invoke only once. Why?

---

Redux Code:

```
function counter(initalState = { count: 0 }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      return Object.assign({}, { count: initalState.count + 1 });
    default:
      return initalState;
  }
}

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    counter
  })
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    count: state.counter.count
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    add: function() {
      dispatch({
        type: "add"
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: please show how you `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: @codekaizer redux code added

Comment: `render` from `Component B` should be invoked only once. that is correct. When the redux state is changed, the `component A` will get notified and it will call its `render` method.
The next step is to update its children. Then `Component B` calls its `render` method.
The flow of state would be something like that:
`state change` -> `Component A re-render` -> `Component B re-render`.
Is that what you have experienced?

Comment: just to be clear, all components uses `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)`? meaning all components are listening to `count`?

Comment: @codekaizer Yes

Comment: Correct. But remember that `A` is the parent, so it kinda gets notified first.

Comment: @BrunoPaulino However, ComponentB connected to redux store by `connect` function of `react-redux`, so when the store changed, the component should update , too? That's the second update

Comment: @hh54188, check [`Reconciliation`](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

Comment: @hh54188 that is correct. But remember that in this case, `B` is a child of `A`, so `A` also plays a role in the lifecycle of `B`.
If they were being rendered in a different hierarchy, let's say siblings' nodes in the DOM tree, they would still call `render` only once. because of the way React handles reconciliation.

Comment: @BrunoPaulino Thank you